# Home network, hacker issues

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, home-networking

I'm new to networking for the most part. I've had issues with a hacker for 10 months and getting no help. After some research I decided to get Wireshark to monitor my network. If it's not coming from within network, someone is working really hard at  making one person look guilty. With that said, can I get a network monitoring 101 really quick? What should I be looking for in particular? I haven't been able to do any course work or attempt my website because the "hacker" is all consuming. All just an FYI, it's only my devices. I have Wireshark installed on a Windows 10 PC. Thank you in advance.

Comment: SuperUser is designed around Q&A where the Answers can be definitive. It's not well suited to requesting or posting tutorials. I've also found that 99% of the time, when someone comes here obsessed with being hacked, it turns out they're having a mental health crisis. We can teach you how to capture packets, but if you don't have deep knowledge of the protocols and haven't seen a ton of completely boring, no-hacking-involved packet traces, you're probably just going to overload yourself with stuff you don't understand and it's just going to freak you out worse even if it's really nothing.

Comment: Thank you Spiff for the response. And no, I really have a hacker, Google, microsoft and comcast advised me mths ago to reach out to the FBI. Which I have. Just waiting to hear back on my report. But you are right its driving me mental. 40 password changes a day , locked out of my new Microsoft account as we speak. Am I desperate and grasping at straws, after finding hidden users in my Macbook pro, maybe I am. But I'm tired, I've dropped 40 lbs, I'm not getting much sleep and it's not getting better.

Comment: Modern OSes have lots of background processes managing behind-the-scenes details of keeping your computer running well. These processes each run as their own hidden user account so that even if one gets compromised, it can't cause problems for the others. This is called "privilege separation" and it is a good thing for security. So macOS has around 100 hidden user accounts, most of which have names starting with underscores. This is a perfectly normal part of the operation of macOS. But people having mental health problems often see that and assume it must be hackers.

Answer (score 1):

> With that said, can I get a network monitoring 101 really quick?

Network monitoring is a professional field and is quite involved, unfortunately there's no "real quick" about it.

Wireshark will let you basically "record" everything coming in from a network interface to a file.  Without knowledge about protocols, you won't understand what's recorded.  Frequently only site developers or application developers will understand things in network traffic without reverse engineering.

Recording a hack in process is also less useful than preventing the hack in the first place with good security practices.

> I've had issues with a hacker for 10 months and getting no help.

Best thing to do at this point is "scorched earth" - basically start over.  I'm assuming this is your home network.

First: you need to take an inventory of every online service you use/sign on to, get a known clean system that's not on your network like a friends computer or even one at a public library if you have no other option.  Do not do this on your home network or a computer you think is hacked.  Then, you should delete accounts you don't use and then change passwords on the others to good, strong passwords.

Second: you need to get your router to a known good state.  Factory reset it and upgrade its firmware to the latest version.  If you are using a very old router or a router with an old custom firmware, or a router that's so old it only supports WPA for example, you may need to get a new router.  If you are stuck using your ISPs router, you need to place it in bridge mode, or create a intermediate network, and use your own router.  You need to set your Wifi password to a long, secure password.

Then, don't place devices on your network until you've done the following, off the network:

- Backed up any important data to a portable flash drive or hard drive.
- Factory reset or wipe/drive reinstall operating system.
- Apply all outstanding updates.
- Use a virus scanning tool to scan files on the portable drive before copying back to a PC.

If this is a company or corporate network, you should seek the services of a competent IT security specialist and do what they tell you.